# net computer returns "Access is denied" for admin user

Tags: windows, active-directory

While logged into my domain controller (Win2k12r2) as the admin account, whenever I try to delete a computer using the command `net computer \\NAME /DEL` I'm always hit with the error:

`System error 5 has occurred. Access is denied`

This is only happening on the CLI, when I go into the AD GUI I am able to remove the computer without any issue. Anyone have any idea why the admin account doesn't have permission to run `net computer`?

Comment: Is the user also a member of the domain admins group?

Comment: Local group membership is `Administrators` and the global group memberships are `Domain Users, Domain Admins, Schema Admins, Enterprise Admins, Group Policy Creator`

Comment: Are you running it from an elevated prompt?

Comment: Yes, `net computer` is being run as administrator